# Why does my code call a different method overload when using params?

Tags: c#, overloading, parameters

Why calls the compiler only the second function and not the first? I have no idea why it's taken the second function.

```
WriteLog("string", "string2" , "string3", "string4");

public static void WriteLog(string text, params string[] pAktionInfos)
{
    WriteLog(text, pAktionInfos);
}

public static void WriteLog(string text, string text2, params string[] pAktionInfos)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text2))
    {
        //Awesome Code
    }
    //Another Awesome Code
}
```

Comment: How is that illogical? It's more specific.

Comment: Its the closest match. The compiler can see you have four formal parameters, the first two of which are strings. The closeset match signature is the one with two formal string parameters. Just the way it is.

Comment: BTW, you have a recursion in the first method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one function can be called and the compiler calls the one that is closest to the original signature and most specific.

You should get a warning about those two functions anyway. If you don't, turn up your warning level.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the compiler the order of recognition goes from explicit parameters to parameters defined with `params`. The more specific a signature is, the sooner it matches.